¿Por que el cmd.exe encuentra las conexiones vpn configuradas, pero el Process de C# no?
Tengo una conexión VPN configurada en windows llamada vVPN, funciona bien si la conecto manualmente e incluso si abro un cmd y ejecuto el comando "rasdial vVPN" se conecta sin problemas y funciona perfecto; el problema es que he desarrollado una app en visual studio con C# sencilla utilizo una instancia de Process (lo normal: con fileName = "rasdial.exe"; arguments = "vVPN", etc) pero el resultado de la ejecución es que la conexión vVPN "no existe".
Acá mi código:
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "rasdial";
psi.Arguments = "vVPN";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

using (Process proceso = Process.Start(psi))
{
    string resultado = proceso.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(resultado);
    proceso.WaitForExit();
    Console.ReadKey();  // Puse esta línea para leer el resultado que arroja.
}

El mensaje que me arroja la variable "resultado" es: The data is invalid.
Acá imagen de la prueba que hago en el cmd:

Espero que me haya explicado lo suficiente, que algún experto me haya entendido y me pueda ayudar, ya casi estoy al borde de la desesperación.

Prueba a ejecutar el cmd.exe desde C# pasando como argumento el comando que deseas que se ejecute:
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "rasdial vVPN";// También puedes probar a poner la ruta donde se encuentra esa aplicación (C:\X\Y\Z\rasdial vVPN)
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

Aquí ejecutas tu VPN como si lo hubieras hecho desde el propio cmd.exe, y además ocultas la ventana del cmd.exe.
Actualización:
El error también pudiera ser que estás omitiendo los caracteres de comillas a la hora de ejecutar tu VPN para ello en tu código original cambia la instrucción:
psi.Arguments = "vVPN";

por:
psi.Arguments = "\"vVPN\"";


Iba con toda la ilusión a probar, pero lamento decirte que no funcionó.

@prentice estoy casi seguro que la solución está cerca, en mi respuesta lo que se hace es utilizar el cmd a través de c#, que debería ser lo mismo que hacerlo manual, quizá debas pararte en el directorio donde está tu VPN usando el comando cd, no obstante dime qué error obtuviste al aplicar mi respuesta

@prentice revisa lo nuevo que puse

Amigo @Japv, noto que pensamos parecido, mientras desarrollaba la app ya había probado esas opciones obteniendo siempre el mismo resultado, o sea, con comillas o si comillas, entre otras opciones. Por eso es que mi pregunta se orienta más a saber si alguien ha tenido la misma expreriencia o si nunca alguien lo ha vivido.

Te cuento que he cambiado mi estrategía y de momento me va mejor. Ahora he creado un batch con el script mencionado en la prueba del cmd arriba y una tarea programada en el Windows que ejecuta ese batch cuando se cumpla cierto evento. Lo menciono por si a otra persona se le despiertan mejores ideas.
